# Multiple live regions and accessibility

Tags: html, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I have a page where more than one part of the page changes upon user input. If I user role="alert" on all of them, only one of them is read out by Jaws/Narrator. Is this expected? What is the workaround?

Comment: Yes. Put all the changes into one container or make one alert area that points to each change.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `role="alert"` this is expected. As JAWS interrupts what ever it was reading to announce the alert and hence ends up announcing only once.

If you wish for all your live regions to be announce use : `aria-live="polite"` instead of `role="alert"`.

This will wait for other things to announce then gracefully announce the changes.

For more info on aria-live have a look at: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-live

Comment: multiple aria-live="polite" on the same action behave the same way, they do not seem to get buffered.